# Ubuntu Dash not on top of windows

Tags: unity-dash, focus

When I press the Windows button the dash used to open on top of windows. It now seems to be under any running applications.

How can I get it to open above Windows, and have focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of points:

1. The "Start Menu" is only called that when it is windows. On ubuntu, we call it the "Dash".
2. By Word I guess you mean Libre Office writer. Very different things - although they do do the same thing.
3. To know if you accidentally changed something, I would need to know what you did. Was there something you did / installed before it changed? Did it change after a restart? Could you edit your question to include those details.

This was a bug that was supposedly fixed:

[Bug #805087](http://pad.lv/bug=805087)

To fix it try restarting...

Comment: A restart helped. And thanks for letting me know that it was called a dash. Also, I just decided to type Word instead of LibreOffice Writer

Comment: That's fine, just Word is a separate program that some people try to run on Ubuntu :) Writer is the shorthand. Thanks for the Accept!